# SSI Include all files in directory?

Tags: ssi

I am new to SSI and need help with this. In one of the HTML files there is an include in UL tag

```
<!--#include virtual="/dataFolder/myfolder/Friday/file1.html"-->
<!--#include virtual="/dataFolder/myfolder/Friday/file2.html"-->
<!--#include virtual="/dataFolder/myfolder/Friday/file3.html"-->
<!--#include virtual="/dataFolder/myfolder/Friday/file4.html"-->
<!--#include virtual="/dataFolder/myfolder/Friday/file5.html"-->
<!--#include virtual="/dataFolder/myfolder/Friday/file6.html"-->
```

Is there any way I can include all of them from directory at once? If I add file7 it should be included too.

Something like

```
<!--#include virtual="/dataFolder/myfolder/Friday/*.html"-->
```

Comment: Have you checked my solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s no SSI instruction doing what you’re asking
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes

You might consider [exec](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_include.html#element.exec) which is supported by Apache if running an external process on every request is a viable solution for you (I woudn't recommend that)

> The exec command executes a given shell command or CGI script

So you just need to feed it a bash command or external scripts that lists all the files in the directory

But `exec` is not supporteed in `nginx`, here's the [discussion](https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,238561,238586#msg-238586)
and [documentation](https://nginx.ru/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssi_module.html)

I don’t know what exactly you’re trying to solve, but I would approach it differently - either use 
`ssi include` + url subrequest to the backend doing whatever you need or concatenate the files into a single bundle[s] and handle them using a regular `ssi include` + a local file path